# Make image cover up the width (centered)

Tags: html, css, image

I'd like to have a image on my front page on a new site cover up the total width and make it change size depending on your resolution, but still have it horizontally centered.

This is the site I'm working on currently: http://jonathan.ohrstrom.nu and I want the whole red part be covered with this image: http://jonathan.ohrstrom.nu/style/img/featured.jpg

How can I do this? This is the css code I have for the div I want the image in:

```
.featured {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I tried this with no success:

```
.featured {
    background-image: url(http://jonathan.ohrstrom.nu/style/img/featured.jpg) no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

But that just didn't load the image at all. Without the `no-repeat` then the image covered the whole width but it repeated itself..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try** make it like this

```
.featured {
    background: url('http://jonathan.ohrstrom.nu/style/img/featured.jpg') no-repeat center center ;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 1;
    }
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-image: url(http://jonathan.ohrstrom.nu/style/img/featured.jpg);background-size: 100% 100%;`

```css
/* GRUNDER */
body {
 background-color: white;
 font-family: verdana;
}

/* MENY */
.menu_wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
 background-color: rgba(45, 45, 45, .9);
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 99;
}
.menu_content {
 width: 1000px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 /*background-color: red;*/
 line-height: 70px;
 color: #a0a0a0;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu_logo {
 float: left;
}
.menu_links {
 float: right;
}

a.menu {
 color: #a0a0a0;
 transition: .1s;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a.menu:hover {
 color: #e5a000;
}

ul.menuList {
 list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
 float: left;
 display: inline;
 margin: 0 10px;
}

/* CONTAINER */
.container {
 width: 1000px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1;
}
.featured {
    background-image: url(http://jonathan.ohrstrom.nu/style/img/featured.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<html><head>
<title>Webutveckling!</title>
<!-- META TAGS -->
<meta name="description" content="En webbyrå som skapar responsiva och smarta websidor åt större och mindre företag!">
<meta name="keywords" content="webutveckling,webbyr�,svensk,stockholm,billig">

<!-- CSS LINKS
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jonathan.ohrstrom.nu/style/style.css"> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jonathan.ohrstrom.nu/style/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,500i" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body>
 <a name="top"></a>
 
 <!-- MENY -->
 <div class="menu_wrapper">
 
  <div class="menu_content">
   
   <div class="menu_logo">
    *LOGO HÄR*
   </div>
   
   <div class="menu_links">
    <ul class="menuList">
     <li><a href="#top" class="menu">hem</a></li>
     <li><a href="#about" class="menu">info</a></li>
     <li><a href="#projekt" class="menu">projekt</a></li>
     <li><a href="#kontakt" class="menu">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   
  </div>
 
 </div>
 
 <!-- WELCOME-BILD -->
 <div class="featured"></div>
 
 <div class="container">
 </div>
 
 <a name="about"></a>
 
 
 <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="http://jonathan.ohrstrom.nu/js/jquery.js"></script>
 
 <script>
  $('a').click(function(){
   $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('[name="' + $.attr(this, 'href').substr(1) + '"]').offset().top
   }, 500);
   return false;
  });
 </script>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I suggest you:

```
.featured {
    background-image: url(http://jonathan.ohrstrom.nu/style/img/featured.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

You can do a lot with the CSS background property:

- Set a color with Hex of RGB.
- Set a image with url() or the single property background-image.
- Center the image horizontally and vertically with percentage or top/center/bottom attributes. You can also set it with the property background-position.
- You can also set the repeat of the image with the attributes repeat/no-repeat. It also has it's own property: background-repeat.
- Set the size of the image with a value or the property background-size. You can also use this property to scale the image in the container like you want with the property cover or contain.
- You can do a lot more, see this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp) for more information on background.